# How to check if product is in basket and if it is in basket replace it with plus and minus?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to check *if the product is in the cart*, and then show (+ or -)? And if it is not in the basket showing *Add to basket button*.
I use the following line of codes, But it shows both plus and minus and add to cart button.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

I am looking for a solution to only show add to cart button. if it is in the cart then show plus and minus.

Comment: _"But it shows both plus and minus and add to cart button"_ How should the product be added to the cart? Via the plus/minus you determine the quantity, then via the add to cart button you add that specific quantity to the cart

Comment: How would you add more qty after you hide add to cart?